# combining two select statements into one table

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have two tables:

```
tbl_origin    tbl_destination

 Origin          Dest
 ------          ----
 AMER            CBU
 PHIL            POT
 TAI             POT
 BAT             CBU
```

i want to get a result in one table:

```
 Origin       Dest
 --------------------
 AMER         CBU
 PHIL         POT
 TAI          POT
 BAT          CBU
```

I have used two select statements but i get results like this:

```
 Origin       Dest
 --------------------
 AMER         CBU
 AMER         POT
 AMER         POT
 AMER         CBU
 PHIL         CBU
 PHIL         POT
 PHIL         POT
 PHIL         CBU
 TAI          POT
 TAI          POT
 TAI          POT
 TAI          POT
 BAT          CBU
 BAT          POT
 BAT          POT
 BAT          CBU
```

I am using MS ACCESS for this. I have tried to use cross join but i seem to get an error.

Comment: do you only have one column for tbl_origin and tbl_destination? so for each row in tbl_origin you want a row in tbl_desitanation side by side?

Comment: Does the match have an importance ? If it has then relying on the order of the entries is asking for trouble. You need to have unique keys and foreign keys .

Comment: What is the relationship between these two tables? how are they joined? are you trying to just concatenate the values in each table, preserving the order? are there the same number of records in each table?

Comment: it has no primary keys or foreign keys. i just want to concatenate the values of each table and preserving its order which has the same number of records in each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is just concatenate based on order, the easiest way is to add a new column in each table call it Id for example and assign each row a unique number or just set it to an identity column type and then you can run the below query.

You new tables would look like

[image]

Query that will give you what you want.

```
select ori.origin, dest.dest 
from tbl_origin ori
inner join tbl_destination dest on dest.id = ori.id
```

If you dont want to add an Id/identity column then you have limited options in Access I am afraid, at least in SQL Server you can use temporary tables etc to get around, but in Access I would think its almost not possible, easiest option is to add a numeric column